# Act on non-text telegram messages in Google Dialogflow. Fallback intent should forward everything

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-webhook

I'm building a chatbot with Telegram and Google Dialogflow. When I integrate Dialogflow into Telegram via the Dialogflow "Integrations" tab, Dialogflow registers as a Webbhook service to intercept all received Telegram messages. Unfortunately, I **cannot act on non-text messages** like stickers, images and Telegram payment checkout messages.

I wish Dialogflow would forward all the received messages to my custom fulfillment webhook in the Fallback intent. In my webhook, I would be able to parse the received body and act on the unsupported telegram messages accordingly.

I know that there is a FACEBOOK_MEDIA event in Dialogflow. This event is fired when an image is sent via a Facebook messenger to Dialogflow. Is there something like a TELEGRAM_MEDIA or even a TELEGRAM_UNSUPPORTED event available?

**I would really like to be able to act on more than just text messages in Dialogflow.**

**Do I need to add another layer between Telegram and Dialogflow to be able to act on all Telegram messages?**

*What I have analyzed so far:*

I forward all Google Dialogflow interaction logs to Google Cloud stackdriver. It seems as if non-text messages are completely ignored by Dialogflow. I see no log entry at all when I send a non-text message to my telegram bot. On the other hand, when I send a text, the log and its JSON payload appears immediately in the stackdriver.

I created a fallback intent in Dialogflow and enabled "Enable webhook call for this intent" in the Fulfillment section. Unfortunately, my fulfillment function doesn't fire on any non-text events. Dialogflow blocks it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I will try to give a possible, but not an out-of-the-box solution to my own question. If someone has a better solution, this would be great.

It seems to me, that at the moment of writing this, a full interaction experience is only possible by **implementing an intermediate layer between Telegram and Dialogflow**. Telegram might contact this intermediate layer, which processes the received message and uses the **Dialogflow SDK/API for the Google NLP goodness**. For the (not yet) supported Telegram messages this intermediate layer must implement its own logic.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there seems to be no way to handle non-telegram text messages via dialogflow, however there is an open report about it here if it may interest https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157202508